# Detect separate figures that intersects each other with Opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to define the coordinates of multiple rectangles appearing randomly in the screen. The width of the rectangles is defined (even if with the contour method i noticed there is a bit of inaccuracy in determine it).
With my python code:

```
yellow = (5,242,206)
while True:
 isFrameValid, frame = capture.read()

 gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 roi = gray [0:300, 0:1920]

 threshold, thresh_image = cv2.threshold(roi, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

 #Select contours
 contours, _ =cv2.findContours(thresh_image,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1,yellow,1)
```

I can only detect the entire block, even trying with different options instead of RETR_EXTERNAL.Looking at my example images, what I'd like to achive is to detect the 3 rectangles (appearing in random position in the screen) so I can correctly determine their coordinates. Are there any ideas or methods I dont know about since im new with Opencv?

[image: what I want]
[image: what I have])

### Example to reproduce the problem with an image

```
import cv2

img= cv2.imread('./IwOXW.png')

yellow = (5,242,206)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
roi = gray [0:300, 0:1920]

threshold, thresh_image = cv2.threshold(roi, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#Select contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_image,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1,yellow,1) 

cv2.imshow('Frame',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

with this image

[image: example]

Comment: If you know that your shapes can only be rectangles, you can try to split the contours to rectangular regions.

Comment: The problem is how to do that, if i use boundingRect it take the whole block, so i dont know the real position of the 3 rectangles. Do you know other methods I can use to determine the rectangles?
I though about create multiple roi only if the width is much bigger than expected and detect them in the single roi, but i dont know if it is the better solution

Comment: from bounding rect you will see that the contour area is far away from the bounding rect area, that show that you will have to split. Now you could try to iteratively find regions within the bounding rect that build rectangles. For example search for largest / biggest interior / inscribed rectangle

Comment: [mre] implies source data. please provide data. the visualized results are interesting to look at but insufficient to reproduce the issue or investigate it.

Comment: I added the same image without the contour, the code provide is pretty similar, but I added also the one that can be used to the new image to test it, a simple image should be sufficient to reproduce the case

Comment: what is this a picture of? what assumptions can be made? how can the picture vary? what information does this picture contain? please explain in the most concrete way possible. avoid abstraction and vagueness, avoid being general. if you must be vague, at least explain why. -- there's no _sure_ way to split that magenta area in general. there are ways to handle this, given some constraints you haven't disclosed yet.

Comment: It is a work project so I would like to not share all the info of the project. About the assumption to do, those are the one exposed in the question, so the width of the rectangles is fixed and the background is black. Those rectangles appear randomly in different position of the screen. But what I am interested in is just how to recognize the rectangles if they touch each other. About how to split that magenta area in general, that is not the topic, I was asking if there are methods im not aware of that can solve the problem of that proposed example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason findCountours can't detect the entire block is because there is no line on the inside for it to detect.

I can think of two options for you to try:

1. Use the contours that you have, and write some smarts to find 90 degree bends, and thus build your rectangles
2. You could investigate using HoughLines to detect the lines. You would probably still have to write some code to take the detected lines and figure out what are rectangles, but it might be simpler with HoughLines as it will give you straight lines to work with. Look for HoughLines in the docs: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/